# for loop and SetPixel() speed improvement not working

Tags: c++

Im trying to code a simple render in c++. 
The main code is simply a for loop that runs through a 2d matrix and draw a pixel on screen on the same coordenates (matrix elements match each pixel).

As this method is relatively slow i tried to split the rendering in 2 (something like in progressive scan), for that i wrote 2 for loops that increase its index by 2. The first one starting at 0 (and writing pixels on even rows and columns) and the second starting at 1 (and drawing on odd). But the pixels seem to overlap eachother leaving scene with half pixels.

The following code works:

```
void render_render() {
  for (int i = 0; i < MAP_HEIGHT; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < MAP_WIDTH; j++) {
      SetPixel(hdc, i, j, MAP[i][j].color);
    }
  }
}
```

But this one doesn't

```
void render_render() {
  for (int i = 0; i < MAP_HEIGHT; i=i+2) {
    for (int j = 0; j < MAP_WIDTH; j=j+2) {
      SetPixel(hdc, i, j, MAP[i][j].color);
    }
  }
  for (int i = 1; i < MAP_HEIGHT; i=i+2) {
    for (int j = 1; j < MAP_WIDTH; j=j+2) {
      SetPixel(hdc, i, j, MAP[i][j].color);
    }
  }
}
```

If someone could tell me what am I doing wrong I would be really thankful.

Comment: maybe I am missing something, but if the slowness was due to cache misses, then after your speed improvement you have double the slowness, no?

Comment: @XinHuang The first loop that executes starts drawing near 10 pixels right to the left margin of the console and then the second starts just in the left side,

Comment: As answered by others, you are skipping some of the pixels. Maybe do two loops with `++i` and `++j`, but checks `if (i+j) % 2 == 0` (1 for second loop) then SetPixel.

Comment: my own experience is that "over-specifiying" in which order something is supposed to be done causes a slow down rather than a speed up. With "over-specifiying" I mean that in principle you should not care in which order the pixels are drawn, so already your first snippet enforces an order that is not really required. More freedom for the compiler means more opportunities for optimization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're stepping by a 2x2 rectangle, inside each 2x2 rectangle there are 4 pixels, not 2.

Neither one of your loops ever touches coordinate (0,1) or (1,0).

TV progressive scan splits the rows into two groups, but the columns are not split.

A much better way to speed up `SetPixel` loops is to prepare the entire block and transfer it to/from graphic memory in a single operation (`SetDIBits`).

Since it looks like you already have the color data stored in an array, look at whether you can't pass your `MAP` pointer directly to `SetDIBits`.  If you have to modify the layout of `MAP` slightly (for example to make it contiguous, or aligned) that is well worth doing because the performance gain will be substantial.

Comment: The calls to SetPixel are a high overhead (one call for each pixex), which is reduced by using hardware support, often called BitBLT or bit blitting.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: blitting yes, but the `BitBlt` function is for moving data between image buffers, to load data from a program buffer into an image buffer the function is `SetDIBits`.

Answer (score 4):

If we imagine the map is of height and width 6, your first pair of loops will set pixels:

```
0,0 0,2 0,4
2,0 2,2 2,4
4,0 4,2 4,4
```

Your second loop will set pixels:

```
1,1 1,3 1,5
3,1 3,3 3,5
5,1 5,3 5,5
```

You can see (and you'll have seen in practice) that this is missing half the pixels. `0,1` for example, is missing.

That's because when you skip alternate rows **and** skip alternate columns, you're only covering a quarter of the pixels.

So, if you stick with this approach, you'll need four passes, or you'll need to cover more pixels in each pass.

Don't expect this to speed up rendering overall -- doing things in a different order doesn't make it faster, but may be more aesthetically pleasing as it fills.

Answer (score 1):

The loops are not equivalent.

The index `(0,1)`, for example, will never occur in the split version.

See the example (where each coordinate is printed to `cout`):

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc232dc929cfa9b2